# Taylor Series of numerical solution of FindRoot

Tags: warning-messages, series-expansion, numerical-value

I have found the inverse to the following equation by using `FindRoot`. I want to have a *Taylor* approximation (say starting from `SDbeta = 0`) of the inverse function. I'm only interested in values of `SDbeta <0.030`.

```
σ =1
Fun0[tau_, W_, Ce_] := 12 σ^2/ Ce^2*(tau^2/W^3 - 3 tau^3/W^4 + 12 tau^5/W^6 - 3 tau^3/W^6 Exp[-W/tau]*(W + 2 tau)^2)
Fun2[tau_] := Sqrt[Fun0[tau, 10, 10]]
InverseFun2[SDbeta_] := tau /. FindRoot[SDbeta == Fun2[tau], {tau,6}][[1]]
InverseFun2[0.01]
```

Simply using Series doesn't lead to a result

```
Series[InverseFun2[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {-0.0251585+x} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {tau} = {6.}.
>       ReplaceAll::reps: {x==1/5 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[tau^2/1000-(3 tau^3)/10000+(3 tau^5)/250000-(3 E^Times[<<2>>] tau^3 Plus[<<2>>]^2)/1000000]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
>       ....

Is it possible to find a Taylor Series if, as in this case, the analytical solution is not available.

**Edit**: I just discovered that there is a thing called NSeries in the Numerical calculus package. Adjusting these lines in the code correspondingly:

```
<< NumericalCalculus`
InverseFun2[SDbeta_?NumericQ] := tau /. FindRoot[SDbeta == Fun2[tau], {tau, 6}][[1]]
NSeries[InverseFun2[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

leads me to the following errors:

> FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {tau} = {22900.1 +0. I}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).
>
> FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
>
> FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

I assume those errors occur because it is trying to compute values of SDbeta that are ill defined.. Is that the case? If so, how to restrict the domain?

Comment: `Fun2[tau]`depends on `\[Sigma]` which isn't defined. That's the reason why FindRoot doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: I forgot to add the first line, where sigma=1. The FindRoot does work (InverseFun2[1] does give proper answer). It's just that I cannot find a numerical Taylor Expansion. I got a bit further now..

Comment: It seems to me `Exp[-W/tau]`, and therefore `Fun2[tau]` also, has an essential singularity at `tau = 0` (corresponding to `SDbeta = x = 0`).  The term that has that factor will contribute zero, if you use the right derivative to define the Taylor series.

Comment: Away from singularities, it might be easiest to use implicit differentiation of the (polynomial) defining relation `SDbeta^2-Fubn2[tau[SDbeta]]^2==0`, then solve for the various derivatives (each will appear linearly in terms of earlier ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you want to solve the equation `Fun2[tau]==sd , sd<.03`

**inverse function**

```
\[Tau][sd_?NumericQ] := tau /. NSolve[sd == Fun2[tau], tau, Reals][[1]]
Plot[\[Tau][sd], {sd, 0.01, .03}, AxesLabel -> {sd, tau=inverseFun2[sd]}]
```

[image]

But if I misunderstood you, you could use Series[...] and InverseSeries[] to solve the problem:

**Series&InverseSeries**

First you have to choose value `tau0` for the series expansion

```
tau0 = tau /. NSolve[Fun2[tau] == 0.03, tau, Reals][[1]]
(*13.984*)
```

series expansion(plus inverse series):

```
ser = Series[Fun2[tau], {tau, tau0, 3}]
invser = InverseSeries[ser , sd]
```

final plot

```
Show[{
Plot[ Fun2[tau] , {tau, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> {0, .1}], 
Plot[Evaluate[Normal[ser ]], {tau, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {0, .1},PlotStyle -> Red],
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Normal[invser ], sd}], {sd, .027, .032},PlotStyle -> Green],
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{\[Tau][sd], sd}], {sd, .027, .032},PlotStyle -> Green]  
}, PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, .1}}, AxesLabel -> {tau, Fun2}, GridLines ->{{tau0}, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. When I use InverseSeries and Series, I do not get a Taylor Series, but instead
    `InverseSeries[1/5 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[E^(-10/x) (SeriesData[x, 0, {Rational[-3, 10000], Rational[-3, 25000], Rational[-3, 250000]}, 3, 6, 1]) + (SeriesData[x, 0, {Rational[1, 1000], Rational[-3, 10000], 0, Rational[3, 250000]}, 2, 6, 1])]].` Could it be possible no Taylor Series is available?

Comment: So what I was doing wrong is trying to find the Taylor Expansion around tau=0 because of the singularity.

Comment: Ok, but the Series around `tau =0 ` exists: `Limit[ Table[Derivative[k][Fun2][tau], {k, 0, 5}], tau -> 0];ser = SeriesData[tau, 0, %, 0, 5, 1]`

Comment: [That code in your previous comment](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVZl7.png) does not work for me, because of an essential singularity mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179624/taylor-series-of-numerical-solution-of-findroot#comment469695_179624). Need to approach along the positive real line to get a series.  Of course the Taylor Series makes a rather poor approximation even around `0.01` in such a case as this.  It's not clear to me that the OP appreciates that.

Comment: @ Michael E2: In MMA (version 11.0.1. Windows64)  `Limit[ Table[Derivative[k][Fun2][tau], {k, 0, 5}], tau -> 0]` evaluates to `{0, Sqrt[3/10]/50, -((3 Sqrt[3/10])/500), -((27 Sqrt[3/10])/20000), (
 207 Sqrt[3/10])/100000, (2241 Sqrt[3/10])/1600000}`

Comment: Apparently, `Limit` has been improved since V11.0.1, since neither the two-sided real limits nor the complex limits exist at `0`.  A fix in my version is to add the option `Direction -> -1`.  (BTW, I do not get notified if you put a space between the @ and my user name.)